# Database level access in Azure SQL managed instance

Tags: sql-server, permissions, users, role, azure-sql-managed-instance

In my Azure SQL managed instance I have two databases, Database_A and Database_B.
User A_ABC has access only to Database_A and he is part of role db_owner.

When the tries to alter a table we are getting the below error

**Query:**
alter table mta.mta_dmn
add active char(3)

**Error:**
Msg 916, Level 14, State 2, Procedure TR_XYZ_DDL_AUDIT, Line 8 [Batch Start Line 0]
The server principal "A_ABC" is not able to access the database "Database_B" under the current security context.

There is no cross database joins or any link between Database_A and Database_B, with Database owner permission my understanding was the user should be able to do any activity within the Database_A. Also there is no procedure 'TR_XYZ_DDL_AUDIT' which exists in either of the databases

I am not able to find why this error is coming/not able to understand this error or able to find a solution. Dropped the login completely and recreated just in case, but the issue persists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that you have a DDL trigger, which is the root cause for this. Check for triggers in Database_A (assuming this is the the database where the table to be altered lives).

Possibly this trigger executes a stored procedure in Database_B which should do some auditing of this operation.

The name TR_XYZ_DDL_AUDIT, gives us some clues.

Comment: Kazari yeah you are right, this trigger was at sever level which was for some auditing purpose. Disabling it resolved this issue. Thanks